# How to add external assembly (.dll) to .NET Core 2.0 on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

I faced some issues regarding adding an external assembly (`.dll`) to my `.NET Core 2.0` console application on **Visual Studio Code** as there are little to none documentation about how you can do it.

Microsoft provides a [very good tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/) about how one can add `NuGet Packages` and Project to project references, but no information on how to add external `dlls`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After some research I managed to get it working.

1. Open your `.csproj` file
2. Below `</PropertyGroup>` tag, add

```html
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Your dll file name">
    <HintPath>Your dll file name.dll</HintPath>
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion> 
    <!-- You may set it to true if your dll has a specific version -->
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

3. Move the `dll` to the **root** folder of your project (where `Program.cs` is)
4. Navigate to the **root** folder of your project using console/terminal and execute `dotnet restore` to import all the references
5. Then, execute `dotnet run`
6. Do **not** remove the dll from your root folder. If you do, you will receive the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Your dll File' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I faced a similar issue today with a .net core 2.0 app.. My work-around was to create a new .net framework web app (not .net core) and add the references there. Then I copied the item groups from the csproj into my .net core project's csproj file. That did the trick.

Comment: Where you mention add code below </PropertyGroup> I had to add above the tag to get dotnet restore to work, not sure if its something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to fix an issue with a Xamarin project and AppCenter!

Answer (score 1):

Right click project
Add existing item > select path to .dll
After added dll in project,right click .dll

> build-action = Content, Copy-to-output-dir = Always/ or if newer

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Community 2019 [v16.8.4]

1. Right click your aspnetcore project
2. `Project Reference...` > Browse > `Browse...`
3. Locate and `Add` your DLL file

[image]
[image]

Comment: Visual Studio Community is not the same as Visual Studio Code, what the question asks about.

Comment: Oh! Thanks I did not realise the question was about VS Code!