# Why I cannot see "Add Reference"

Tags: vb.net, add-references-dialog

I am new to visual studio, I am trying to add "Inventor" reference, I added it from Solution expolrere - Dependancies - Rightclick - Add project reference. However, it may not inserted correctly because I can see it doen't get intelegency in code when I try to accesss the Inventor API.
Second thing,Does the Add project reference and Add reference is different thing?

[image]

Moreover, why I cannot see "Add reference" instead of "Dependancies"?
I am using Visual studio 2019.

Comment: Because you're using .NET Core / .NET 5+. If you want it the old way, start a .NET Framework project instead.

Comment: See: [Add reference to assembly .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65697196/8967612)

Comment: thanks, it solved my issue